# dotnet-gcdump unexpected dump size and impact

Tags: .net-core, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm running a simple CRUD app built with ASP.NET Core and EF Core 3.1 in a docker swarm cluster on ubuntu. I'm only using managed code.
The container has a `10GB` memory limit specified. I can inspect a running container and verify that this limit is actually set, I also see that `DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER` is set to `true`. When the app is started the memory consumption is about `700MB` and it slowly builds up. Once it reaches `7GB` (I see it in container generic stats) I start getting `OutOfMemoryException`s and it stays at this level for days. So the first question is

1. Why doesn't it go up to 10 GB?

Anyway I expect memory leaks so I have a [dotnet-gcdump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-gcdump) tool installed in this same container so I go ahead and collect the dump for future analysis with `dotnet-gcdump collect`. Once I execute this command I see the memory consumption of the running container drops from `7GB` to `3GB` and stays at this level. The resulting `.gcdump` file itself size though is only `~200MB` with nothing suspicious in it. So next questions are

2. How does the collection of a dump reduce memory consumption? I'd assume it's doing GC with LOH compaction but it doesn't mention it in the docs.
3. Why isn't this memory freed automatically if the tool is able to do it?
4. Why is a resulting dump only 200 MB in size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [gcdump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-gcdump#description) documentations explains: *"GC dumps are created by **triggering a GC** in the target process, turning on special events, and **regenerating the graph of object roots** from the event stream"*.

Thus, it directly answers your question 2 - it triggers full GC, which may or may not be compacting, but it collects gen2 for sure. It also answers question 4 - it is not a "memory dump" but a special kind of diagnostics data about the objects graph (depndencies and typenames), without the data itself.

And regards to the questions 1 and 3 - it is an example of the GC being "not aggressive" enough. It is kind of the "living on the edge" problem when the process almost meets the containers limits and GC sometimes is not able to interpret it. In other words, it thinks it has enough space, but it doesn't. Please, be warned that this is a super-oversimplification. In such a case full GCs may not happen or happen too late. I would confirm that by observing the process by the [`dotnet-trace`](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/master/documentation/dotnet-trace-instructions.md) with `gc-collect` profile.

As a solution, [consider setting the limit manually, by using `GCHeapHardLimit`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/running-with-server-gc-in-a-small-container-scenario-part-1-hard-limit-for-the-gc-heap/), to some clearly smaller value like 8GB.

Comment: thanks, I examined the gcdump, unfortunately there is no way to see the sum of all values per column but it looks like the sum would be 50 MB max even with "just my code" disabled, how do I read and use this data?

Comment: How did you examine it? AFAIK you should be able to use Visual Studio, or use PerfView if not.

Comment: I used visual studio, the "size column" was about 1 MB for 5 biggest items and less than 100k for everything below